# Delete the characters _00 or .00 if exists at the end of the string in oracle or informatica

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, informatica

My Source (Oracle) data is having below values. We need to delete `_00` or `.00` or `_` if exists at the end.  Can you please provide some SQL query to get the below target values.

SOURCE VALUES:

```
123450_00
12356_00
123455678
34569_
67589
123400.00
```

TARGET MUST BE

```
123450
12356
123455678
34569
67589
123400
```

I tried using `rtrim(columnname,'_00')` but if i use this, `'0'` before `_` is also getting deleted which is not correct.

Comment: (Second-guessing my own answer) Are you 100% sure you want to get rid of the `_00` completely? Is it possible that the `_` is used as a thousand / hundred separator in your input data (in that case, you should replace `_00` with `00` - otherweise, you'll divide your value by 100 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions for this, namely `regexp_replace()`:

```
select value,
  regexp_replace(value, '[_.][0-9]*$', '') 
from demo;
```

This will replace a

- literal `_` or `.`
- followed by 0 or more digits `[0-9]*`
- at the end of the string `$`

with the empty string.

**Schema**

```
create table demo(value varchar2(30 char));

insert into demo values('123450_00');
insert into demo values('12356_00');
insert into demo values('123455678');
insert into demo values('34569_');
insert into demo values('67589');
insert into demo values('123400.00');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9d3a/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working in both oracle and informatica expression transformation.

Comment: @Rajesh You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it (by clicking the check button next to it) - that way, it won't appear in the list of unanswered questions anymore.